# How pass selected value of dropdown inside same page's div using php function without submitting the page

Tags: javascript

```
Here is my code:
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
$data="data";
//echo "data: ".$data;
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]))
{
    //echo "name is set";
    $function2call = $_POST["name"];
    switch($function2call)
    {
       case 'productCategory' : getPidAdd();break;
        // other cases
    }
}

function getPidAdd()
{
    global $data;
    if(isset($_POST["value"]) && !empty($_POST["value"]))
    {
        echo "before: ".$data;
        $data=$_POST["value"];
        echo "after selected product type: ".$data;
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "pcategory not set";
    }
    exit;
}

function datafetch()
{
    global $data;
    echo $data;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPdata()
{
    //alert("fucntion called");
    productCategory=document.getElementById("pdata").value;
    //document.write(productCategory);
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Demo.php',
            data: {name: 'productCategory',value: productCategory},
            success:function(data) {
            alert(data); 
            }
            });
   document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block";
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<form id="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on">
<p>
    <label for="pdata">Data Type:</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="pdata" name="pdata" onchange="getPdata()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST["pdata"]) &&  $_POST["pdata"]=='1') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>data1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST["pdata"]) &&  $_POST["pdata"]=='2') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>data2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST["pdata"]) &&  $_POST["pdata"]=='3') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>data3</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST["pdata"]) &&  $_POST["pdata"]=='4') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>data4</option>
    <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST["pdata"]) &&  $_POST["pdata"]=='5') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>data5</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div id="div1" name="div1" style="border-style:solid;border-color:black;border-width:2px;border-radius:8px;color:black;width:100%;display:none;overflow-y:scroll;max-height:150px" align="left">
    <?php

    echo datafetch();//get the value of selected data option
    ?>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output

[image]

I am getting the selected value of dropdown in onchange() function of javascript.From there I am passing that value to php using AJAX.And based on that I am calling a function to get the value and assign it to global variable. The div will be visible only if we change the value of drop down.But here the div is not returning the changed value of global variable
How the change in the global variable is not reflected?
How can I get the selected value of dropdown into the div's content?
Can anyone suggest something?Thanks

Comment: Why the php tag is not added?

Comment: You could return some response from php side and on ajax call success function you can do this div operation using javascript.I guess it would be much easier

Comment: I have added the tags

Comment: @M14 yes that will work fine but once I get the data in the div I want to fire a sql query and then show the results in the div

Comment: On ajax success show the div and got for another ajax call

Comment: But I want to get the selected value of  2 different drop downs in my case and once I get both the values then only I can fire the sql query and show the result in tabular format.

Comment: if you want to wait for two dropdowns to be populated, then instead of handling the "onchange" event, which only applies to a single dropdown, have a separate button which the user must click to submit their query, and when that's clicked then trigger your ajax call and get the values  of both dropdowns to send to the server.